# Selective download iCloud Drive on iOS

Tags: ios, icloud, data-synchronization

I updated my iCloud Storage to 200GB and I planned to put all my important files from my macbook pro into the iCloud. Unfortunately there is no such thing as the selective sync feature in Dropbox.

Will iCloud load all those files on my iOS Devices (iPhone, iPad Pro) automatically or is it possible to make a choice (through the "cloud"-button beside the filenames)? Is it possible (I didn't find a button for that) to delete local copies while leaving them in the cloud?

Thanks in advance and kind regards!

Comment: It's the other way around. iCloud Drive doesn't sync files onto iOS devices; it keeps them in the cloud and only downloads them to the device on as "as needed" basis. I don't know when it then deletes the local copy again.